# Transfer code from one computer to another via Git

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have some code I have not committed nor pushed to the branch I am working on on a local computer because the code is not working yet. However, I simply want to move that code from one computer to another without affecting the branch. How would I do so? For example, my code is on computer A, and I am working off of a branch called 'develop' which I pull and update code from. I don't want to change anything in develop but I want to move the code I have written to computer B. How would I do so? If anyone could help that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Create a new branch off of `develop`, commit changes there and push new branch, pull new branch on computer B.  When done, merge back to `develop`.

Answer (score 6):

I would create a new branch and push it to that branch.

```
git branch incomplete-code
git checkout incomplete-code
git commit -a
git push origin incomplete-code
```

You can then clone the repo on your own computer and work on the incomplete-code branch

```
git clone <repo address>
git checkout incomplete-code
```

After your code is complete, you can merge the branch as such

```
git checkout develop
git merge incomplete-code
```

There might be various ways to do it but this is one I can think of.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But you need to do a `git fetch` before you do `git checkout incomplete-code` otherwise your second computer doesn't know about a newly created repository on the server.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do the transfer using git you must commit the changes to the local repo on computer A. If you don't want to do that then you should simply copy the changed files from computer A to computer B outside of git.

If both computers have access to a central git repository you can do as others suggest and commit the code to a new branch on computer A, push the new branch up to the central repo, and then pull the new branch down onto computer B.

If computer B is capable of pulling directly from computer A then you can commit the code to a new branch (or even to the existing 'develop' branch on computer A, just don't push that commit to any pubic repo) and then on computer B pull that commit directly from computer A.

If the computers are not connected except through a sneakernet you can use [git bundles](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) to transfer the committed code from computer A to computer B.

You can also commit the code on computer A, use `git format-patch` to create a patch file, copy the patch to computer B, and use `git apply` to apply the patch.